# Jquery, Ajax JSONP returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I have successfully connected and calledback my data from crossbrowser using Ajax retrieving JSON via JSONP, however with the data that comes back is the correct callback of Sydney but 7 other undefined with it. Any ideas where I am going wrong.

### Result

```
undefined
undefined
Sydney
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

### Code

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&HotelID=187477&type=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {

        $.each(data.HotelInformationResponse, function(i,data) {
            var div_data = " <div class='box'>"+data.city+"</div> ";

            $(div_data).appendTo("#target");
        });
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        //alert('no');
    }
});
```

Im getting the retur here

```
Request URL:https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&HotelID=187477&type=json&callback=jQuery110205582368678878993_1376612818209&_=1376612818210
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.eancdn.com
Referer:http://www.nelsonbaynsw.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
cid:55505
minorRev:99
apiKey:cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf
locale:en_US
HotelID:187477
type:json
callback:jQuery110205582368678878993_1376612818209
_:1376612818210
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:none
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:4440
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 16 Aug 2013 00:27:02 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:EAN
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Mashery-Responder:prod-p-worker-lax-03.mashery.com
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is coming back from the ajax call?

Comment: Open the developer tools, open the network tab, there you can see your ajax request, click your request and see the response, check if you are getting the expected response or paste response here.

Comment: If you are not expecting multiple hotel results in your ajax, why are you using `$.each(data`? just make sure `data.HotelInformationResponse` is not undefined and read it directly. the undefined that you see is from other properties of the ajax data object e.g. length, ...

Comment: it looks like the server is returning city information for all the records

Comment: try to print the response to console using `JSON.stringify(data)` and share the same

Answer (score 0):

HotelInformationResponse on your json response is an object, not an array. So when you do this `$.each(data.HotelInformationResponse,...` you are iterating over each property of it. And only one of its properties has a property called city, which is `HotelSummary`, that is why all the others are undefined. All you probably want to do is:

```
success: function(data) {
    var city = data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary.city;
    $('<div class="box">').text(city).appendTo("#target");
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

You can certainly use `each` with an object. It is just not as common as using an array. A practical example of array usage, where you list the name and city of three different hotels:

```
var hotels = [{name:'Hotel1', city:'Paris'},{name:'Hotel2', city:'London'},{name:'Hotel3', city:'Auckland'}];
$.each(hotels, function(i,hotel) {
    var div_data = " <div class='box'><p>Name: "+hotel.name+"</p><p>City: "+hotel.city+"</p></div> ";
    $(div_data).appendTo("#target");
});
```

Notice that by using property name, you know exactly what and where to place your data. And when iterating over an object, you are more likely to get a random list of properties:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary, function(i, propertyValue){
        // propertyValue could be a name, city, town, id...
    });
}
```

The most common usage on this case, assuming that you know the properties you want to use, would not use iteration, and would be something like my first example. But of course, all three can be used based on what you want to achieve.

Comment: What if I wanted to return a all the objects, would I be better to do them as an array data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary [city, id, town] or do them as data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary.city, data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary.id

Comment: You can keep them as objects and then use each: $.each(data.HotelInformationResponse.HotelSummary, function(i, propertyValue){//use propertyValue});

Comment: I thought not to use .each() for an object as in your first posting. could you write the whole function so I can see

Comment: You can. It just depends on what you want to achieve. I have update the answer, hope it clarifies.

Comment: Yes thanks it does clarify, however what if I am using JSONP to access across domain where I want to access each Hotel name and information turn it into a string to display. These values would be a variable

Comment: [{name:'I do not know',city:'its a variable being returned'},{name:Some other one that it is going to get',city:not sure}]. You do not want to write every value as these are the values you want returned